# Understanding the Probability that A realizes before B in a mission whose duration is T unit

Tags: probability

$A$: random variable to denote time to failure for equipment E_A

$B$: random variable to denote time to failure for equipment E_B

$A$ and $B$ are independent.

$P(A◁B)(T)$ : Probability that A realizes **before** B in a mission whose duration is T unit.

**example scenario**:

$A$ and $B$ both exhibit exponential distribution.

E_A failure rate: $\lambda_A=5E-3$ /hours

E_B failure rate: $\lambda_B=9.4E-3$ /hours

duration: $100$ hours

what is $P(A◁B)(T)$ ?

**I tried: (found equation below in a paper. I can understand the equation.)**

$$P(A◁B)(T)=\int_0^T \biggl( pdf_A(t)*(1-CDF_B(t)) \biggr) dt$$

**my questions:**

1. integral result is 0.2650 if $\int$ time range is $0$ to $100$
2. integral result is 0.3472 if $\int$ time range is $0$ to $\infty$
3. Which one is correct, $0.2650$ or $0.3472$? Why?

**my confusion** to ask question 3 is why result depends on time? I feel that only the values of $\lambda$s are significant here since exponential rate is constant and exponential distr. is memoryless.

it's been >15 years since my statistics lessons. May you please help? regards

Comment: What if time is 1 hour? Or half an hour? Then you likely end up with a situation where neither fail in which case A does not fail before B. This is why you need to time into consideration.

Comment: Even for time = 100, there's the possibility that neither fail in which case A does not fail before B. So you need to take that possibility into account as well.

Comment: sure. 1st  mission (0 to100)=26.5% , 2nd mission: 6.16% , 3rd mission 0.0616 , 4th mission 0.0146 and so on. Sum of these probabilities is 34.72%. **In my real life related question I don't have any $T_0$ or $T_1$. I just have duration**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your calculation in 1 is smaller than your calculation in 2 is that it is a more specific event.  The respective events for these probability calculations are:

$$\begin{matrix}
1. & & & & & A < B \ \text{ and } A < T \\[6pt] 
2. & & & & & A < B. \\[6pt] 
\end{matrix}$$

As to which is correct, that depends on which event you are interested in.